# Google Custom Search Engine for www.example.com/* but exclude example.com/*

Tags: google-custom-search

I am having trouble setting up the following Google CSE:

1. It should search for URLs like http://www.example.com/*.
2. But it should **exclude** URLs like http://example.com/* because that is a different website.

I first setup the search engine to look for `www.example.com` but that will include all URLs like http://example.com/*.  I then tried add a setup to exclude `example.com` but that will exclude all URLs like http://www.example.com/* (so there will be no results.) I then tried several possible variants I can think of, but the results all fall into these two categories (all or none.)

Comment: Can you give the real url? It is not easy to find example like you mentioned (www being a special subdomain name)

Comment: Of course, [the one with `www`](http://www.e-info.org.tw/) and [the one without `www`](http://e-info.org.tw/).  They are in Chinese, though.